# Python: Requests to local server not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the python library `requests` to attempt to send a post request to my local server. I have successfully installed and imported requests--I just can't seem to post or get data from my local server.

Both the server and my python program are on the same machine, the server is currently Django's development server.

What I am trying:

```
domain = 'localhost:8000'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'
data = 'some data to be sent'
r = requests.post(domain, data auth=(user,password))
```

Exception raised:

```
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'localhost:8000'
```

I have done all the basic things like ensuring that the server was up and running. I have also tried to substitue localhost with 127.0.0.1:8000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a proper URL including protocol:

```
domain = 'http://localhost:8000'
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I will select this answer when this website allows me to do so!

Comment: Daniel, can you by any chance point me to any resources about how to handle these POST requests from Django? I would post another question but at this point it would be too broad and I fear it will just be closed or downvoted away.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking I'm afraid. Handle what requests, where? Can you not show a concrete example of what you're trying to do and the problems you are experiencing?

Comment: Sorry, it was broad, I will provide some more details. So using the requests library (which you helped me do), a python program has sent a POST request (that includes a string) to my Django app. Now I would like to "handle" or process that request in the Django app, specifically by creating a new database entry with the string received. Everything I have read online assumes I am using a form to get this POST data--but I am instead using a python program that sends said request.

Comment: That seems specific enough for a separate question. But I still don't really understand where your problem is, there is no difference if the request comes from a form or a separate app, you can still access `request.POST` in exactly the same way.